# HTML localStorage is null on Android when using webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, local-storage

I am trying to use localstorage from my local web APP, here is the WebView initialization part:

```
static class MyWebView extends WebView
        {
            public MyWebView(Context context)
            {
            super(context);

            this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            //enable support for DOM Storage and Database
            this.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            this.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


            String databasePath = context.getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();

            this.getSettings().setDatabasePath(databasePath);


            this.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);
        } }
```

and Here is the test app on JavaScript:

```
function testStorage() 
    {
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        if (storage) {
            try {
                storage.setItem("name", "Hello World!"); //saves to the database, “key”, “value”
            } catch (e) {

                    alert(e.message); //data wasn’t successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
            }
            document.write(storage.getItem("name")); //Hello World!
            storage.removeItem('name'); 
        }
        else {
            alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Because Storage is' + storage);
        }
    }
```

but the problem is that the localStorage is always null, I have checked the permissions and  created a WebChromeClient with

```
@Override
            public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url,
                    String databaseIdentifier,
                    long currentQuota,
                    long estimatedSize,
                    long totalUsedQuota,
                    WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater)
            {
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2);
            }
```

which never gets called. 
Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set your custom WebCromeClient on the WebView?

Comment: yes, I have using webView.setWebChromeClient ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried just enabling the setting as per this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5934650/85472