# Android standalone application does supports localstorage?

Tags: android, jquery, html, local-storage

I am developing an Android HTML5 application.

I am not using any of the Android API apart from loading my main.html file. The rest of the application runs through HTML5 and jQuery mobile.

I use localstorage in my app to store some user related data. When I test this in my local browser by loading the main.html file everything works well. But when I run the same application on Android simulator I don't see the values in the app which I am loading from localstorage.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings(); // TO enable JS      
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // To enable Localstorage 
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
    webView. webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html"); 
    setContentView(webView); 
}
```

So my ultimate question whether a standalone android HTML 5 app supports localstorage or not?

If not what is the alternative apart from data storage?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the below code to enable HTML5 Local store in android webview

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Also you'd need to make sure the target SDK is 2.1 or higher.

Details here : [Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)