# Android - WebView html5 local storage not persistant after app update

Tags: javascript, android, html, local-storage

I have an application that uses HTML5 local storage. The data in local storage is persistent throughout the app, while the app is open or closed. However, when the app was updated from the store, the local storage was erased. Is there a way to prevent the loss of local storage during app updates? Thanks!

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);        
mWebSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Here is a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69860) created by [@steffmeister](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3659564/steffmeister). (originally posted as an answer)

Answer (score 3):

There are answers to this posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)

The answer given by Mr Boyfox was

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}
```