# How to use persistent storage in webview of an Android app

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I developed an Android application via `cordova` which running inside a webview. How can I make the app use `persistent storage` in chromium? It only consumes `temporary storage`. The reason I need to use `persistent storage` is that I can request more spaces. If I use `temporary storage` and it runs of out maximum limit, the temporary storage will remove old data on the database.

I run below code in chrome console and it gives me `we are using  0  of  0 bytes` which means there is 0 space in persistent storage I can use.

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota (
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    },
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

Then I run below code to request more storage:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
    100 * 1024 * 1024, function(grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, (d) => console.log(d), e => console.error(e));

    }, function(e) { console.log('Error', e); }
);
```

after that nothing happens and it is still 0 storage space I can use. I wonder how I can use persistent storage in webview. Do I need to specify any permission for that?

The permission for my app is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have checked another question [Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage) but it is quite different with mine. I am asking to grant persistent storage permission for my webview but that question doesn't explain how to use `persistent storage` instead it uses `temporary storage` which is the default storage in webview.

I have set `setDatabaseEnabled(true)` on java code but it doesn't use `persistent storage`. In stead, it uses `temporary storage`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)

Comment: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560264/android-webview-html5-local-storage-not-persistant-after-app-update) also seems related.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for your comments. I have checked these two other questions but none of them use `persistent storage` in the webview. All they are doing is to use `temporary storage`.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve your issue?

Comment: There years later... any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[setDatabaseEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabaseEnabled(boolean)) seems to be the only method still available:

> Sets whether the database storage API is enabled. The default value is `false`.

even if one cannot change the location of the database anymore; as
[setDataBasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) reads:

> **This method was deprecated in API level 19.**
>
> Database paths are managed by the implementation and calling this method will have no effect.

Using `JavaScriptInterface` might be a possible workaround for persisting data; for [example](https://github.com/didimoo/AndroidLocalStorage).

The Cordova [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) also lists some possible options, in comparison.

Comment: I have set `setDatabaseEnabled(true) ` on java code but it doesn't use `persistent storage`. In stead, it uses `temporary storage`.

Comment: @ZhaoYi if it doesn't work directly with the `WebView` (Cordova is just a custom version), using SQLite as storage backend might be the best option - this at least persists until the app had been uninstalled... the default location for that database is internal storage (works without requesting run-time permissions).

Comment: I don't have problem on persisting the data on local storage. The problem is the storage is used by webview is temporary which means it will remove data if it runs out of the maximum storage limit. And I can't claim more temporary storage. I don't mind using either SQLite or IndexDB as long as they can use persistent storage.

Comment: @ZhaoYi those SQLite plugins use almost the same storage facility as most Android apps use and also work with iOS & Windows... still, some JS code would need to be migrated, but queries are quicker and there is no limit in database size; except that the cursor window might be limited to at most 2mb (at least on Android this might apply, unsure about the other platforms).

Comment: The limit size is not determined by any database, like SQLite or IndexedDB. It is limited by browser.  Checkout here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage

Comment: @ZhaoYi for `LocalStorage`, it's +/- 5mb overall and it even might be dropped, as you describe it...the Cordova `WebView` is not exactly the same as `Chrome`; only [CustomTabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) is the common `Chrome`... for a simple key/value store, a simple table with two columns already suffices.

Comment: So there is no way to make indexedDB to use persistent storage on webview?