# remember last page in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am making a jquery mobile app
With phonegap
It is like a turorial in how to read Quran
I want it to keep the progress the user nad made and resume it when reopen
Any help or clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Store the last page visited in a cookie and redirect to that after the app loads

**Demo** -- visit a page re-click run

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgz38s4/

**Code**

```
//check if the lastpage exists and redirect to the page

if ($.cookie('lastpage')) {
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#"+$.cookie('lastpage'))    
}


//store the page visited in a cookie

$(document).on("pageshow", function (e, data) {
 var pageid = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' );
  $.cookie('lastpage', pageid)  
});
```

you need include the Jquery cookie plugging for cookies to work

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

ahh just realized you are using Cordova and may have issues with storing cookies in Android webview. If you do and the above code(setting and reading the cookie)  doesn't work then

Check here on how to enable local storage instead for Android webview

[Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage/5934650#5934650)'

and here on how to store and read data within the App, its easy

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/