# How to get storage permission in Webview?

Tags: android, html

**i set input file in html body and use this in android WebView but not grant permission and input
button not work**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android webview & localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899087/android-webview-localstorage)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.