# Access Local Storage in Android Studio WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, local-storage, websmart

How do I access local storage in android studio? Basically what I've got is a simple webview of a website. In the javascript section of the website I'm setting up some values. But when I open the app the values doesn't show up.

First of all does the local storage work in that case? If yes how? What do I need to change.

Getting the values in another program

```
var testCode,month,day,year;
testCode = localStorage.getItem('testCode');
month = localStorage.getItem('month');
day = localStorage.getItem('day');
year = localStorage.getItem('year');
```

Setting the values

```
localStorage.setItem('testCode',testCode);
localStorage.setItem('month',month);
localStorage.setItem('day',day);
localStorage.setItem('year',year);
```

FYI the whole website is made of modules using IBM WebSmart ILE and IBM db2.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("url for redirection");
}
```

What I do is if the local storage items are null then redirect to unauthorized page else redirect to the main page. The flow is user opens the link in text message and authenticates himself/herself then a link is present which would redirect to the application which would check for local storage items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899087/150978